# What is the Objective C equivalent of EventWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, objective-c, asynchronous

What is the Objective C equivalent of EventWaitHandle in .NET?

Comment: Please realize that when you ask "What is the equivalent of functionality C from language A in language B" without further details, you can only get answers from the subset of programmers that know both A and B.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after!

Comment: Also; your question ultimately doesn't make sense.  You are asking a question that is specific to API, not language and, thus, requires actually understanding the targeted API.  Your question is akin to asking "I'm working on an electric train? What is the equivalent to the timing belt in a car engine?"  There may be something slightly synonymous, but you won't be able to effectively leverage it without understanding the overall architecture.

Comment: It makes sense if you understand EventWaitHandle in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the closest thing I found was [NSConditionLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConditionLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can set it to wait like this:

```
[condLock lockWhenCondition: 1];
[condLock unlockWithCondition:0];
```

and then signal it like this:

```
[condLock lock];
[condLock unlockWithCondition:1];
```

Thanks to [Lukassen's blog](http://lukassen.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/nssemaphore-missing/) for providing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(someMethod) waitUntilDone:YES]
```

There are obviously several different options for this, but at the core, you want to thread something off. You can read up on the different options from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).